# tlmgr not found when run as root

Tags: environment-variables, latex, texlive

I have installed TeXLive and added `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux` to my `$PATH` through `/etc/environment`, so I should be able to run `tlmgr` from the terminal. I am able to do that as non-root user:

```
johndoe@pc:~$ tlmgr update --all
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

I get an error but there is nothing strange, to update the packages I obviously have to run `tlmgr` as root - and that's where I am having troubles:

```
johndoe@pc:~$ sudo tlmgr update --all
[sudo] password for johndoe: 
sudo: tlmgr: command not found
```

Still, if I check the content of `/etc/environment` it includes `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux`:

```
johndoe@pc:~$ cat /etc/environment
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux"
```

In a previous Ubuntu installation I managed to fix that, so I'm certain that there is a way to do that, but I don't have a clue about what I did. Any suggestion?

I don't know what additional information could be useful, please ask in the comments if needed.

## Update

I'm working with Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine). I installed TeXLive "over the internet" because the ["Acquire TeX Live" page](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html) recommends to do so.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What was wrong with installing TeXLive from the [repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=texlive-full)?

Comment: @N0rbert I have just updated the question.

Comment: Condidering setting sudo secure_path. For more details see : https://superuser.com/questions/927512/how-to-set-path-for-sudo-commands

Answer (score 3):

I am also having this problem. Specifically:

- I can run `tlmgr`.
- sudo cannot run `tlmgr`, giving "`sudo: tlmgr: command not found`".
- sudo **can** run `tlmgr` if I give it the explicit path to that file `/usr/local/texlive/.../tlmgr` (so I know the problem is not with permissions on `tlmgr`).

I investigated and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12998638) to [Command not found when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo).

It seems when I installed TeX Live 2020, I've added the texlive directory to the path for my user but not the superuser. To test this, run:

```
env | grep ^PATH
```

to see *your* path, and then

```
sudo env | grep ^PATH
```

to see the path of the superuser. For me, the superuser path is missing the texlive directory, which is why I can run `tlmgr` but not `sudo tlmgr`.

Options:

1. You can ask sudo to run giving the full path to tlmgr (find this using `locate tlmgr` if you don't know where it is).
2. You can ask sudo to run with *your* path instead of the superuser path by running `sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" tlmgr`.
3. You can edit the superuser path, if you are confident you know what you are doing, using `visudo`.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. If tlmgr was installed successfully, try the following command to find your tlmgr path:

```
which tlmgr
```

Then you can substitute tlmgr with the absolute path in your terminal command like the following:

```
sudo /usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --all
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04 MATE and TeXLive 2020.  Formerly, I got over this issue by modifying the permission of the TEXDIR folder (e.g., /usr/local/texlive/2020).  But this is not so elegant.  I suppose there is better way to solve this issue.

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.